# postgresql full text search query to django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, full-text-search

I was following the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-controls.html) on FullTextSearch in postgresql.  I've created a tsvector column and added the information i needed, and finally i've created  an index.
Now, to do the search i have to execute a query like this

```
SELECT *, ts_rank_cd(textsearchable_index_col, query) AS rank
FROM client, plainto_tsquery('famille age') query
WHERE textsearchable_index_col @@ query
ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I want to be able to execute this with Django's ORM so i could get the objects. (A little question here: do i need to add the tsvector column to my model?)
My guess is that i should use extra() to change the "where" and "tables" in the queryset

Maybe if i change the query to this, it would be easier:

```
SELECT * FROM client
WHERE plainto_tsquery('famille age') @@ textsearchable_index_col
ORDER BY ts_rank_cd(textsearchable_index_col, plainto_tsquery(text_search)) DESC LIMIT 10
```

so id' have to do something like:

```
Client.objects.???.extra(where=[???])
```

Thxs for your help :)
Another thing, i'm using Django 1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caveat: I'm writing this on a wobbly train, with a headcold, but this *should* do the trick:

```
where_statement = """plainto_tsquery('%s') @@ textsearchable_index_col 
                     ORDER BY ts_rank_cd(textsearchable_index_col, 
                                         plainto_tsquery(%s)) 
                     DESC LIMIT 10"""

qs = Client.objects.extra(where=[where_statement], 
                          params=['famille age', 'famille age'])
```

If you were on Django 1.2 you could just call:

```
Client.objects.raw("""
SELECT *, ts_rank_cd(textsearchable_index_col, query) AS rank
FROM client, plainto_tsquery('famille age') query
WHERE textsearchable_index_col @@ query
ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 10;""")
```

Comment: i've tried it but it throws an error saying that there's a problem on the syntax of the query which is weird because i took the qs.query and executed directly in the database, and it works fine, i guess the problem is in the single quotes in the "plainto_tsquery('%s')"